# Is Spring batch's default behavior is to process next item only after first item finished?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

After reading [this article](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/scalability.html#scalability) about the possibilities of scaling and parallel processing in `Spring-Batch` we were wondering, what is the out-of-the-box behavior of Spring-batch?

Let's say our job has reader, 5 steps and a writer.

Will Spring-batch read one item, pass it through all the 5 steps, write it and only then move on to the next item? Something like a giant `for loop`?

Or is there some parallelism, so while item A is moved on to step 2, item B is read and handled to step 1?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding how Spring Batch works.  Let me start with that, then go into parallelism.

A chunk based step in Spring Batch consists of an `ItemReader`, an optional `ItemProcessor`, then an `ItemWriter`.  Each of these obviously supports composition (Spring Batch provides some components for using composition in both the `ItemProcessor` and `ItemWriter` phases).  Within that step, Spring Batch reads items until a given condition is met (typically chunk size).  Then that list is iterated over, passing each item to the `ItemProcessor`.  Finally, a list of all of the results from the `ItemProcessor` calls is passed in a single call to the `ItemWriter`.  The concept of reading once, then doing multiple steps, then writing really isn't how Spring Batch works.  The closest we get would be a single `ItemReader`, then using composition to create a chain of `ItemProcessor` calls, then a single call to an `ItemWriter`.

With that being said, Spring Batch provides a number of parallelism options.  There are five different options for scaling Spring Batch jobs.  I won't go into details about each because that's beyond the scope of this and clearly discussed in other StackOverflow questions as well as the documentation.  However, the list is as follows:

1. **Multithreaded steps -** Here each chunk (block of items processed within a transaction) is executed within a different thread using Spring's `TaskExecutor` abstraction.
2. **Parallel steps -** Here a batch job executes multiple, independent steps in parallel again using Spring's `TaskExecutor` abstraction to control the theads used.
3. **AsyncItemProcessor/AsyncItemWriter -** Here each call to the `ItemProcessor` is called in it's own thread.  The resulting `Future` is passed to the `AsyncItemWriter` which unwraps the `Future` and the results are persisted.
4. **Partitioning -** Spring Batch allows you to partition a data set into multiple partitions that are then executed in parallel either via local threading mechanisms or remotely.
5. **Remote chunking -** The last option is to have a master reading the data, then sending it to a pool of workers for processing and writing.

Comment: So if you have bulk of 10 items, will there be any parallel processing? or they will be handled one by one, till bulk writing them all?